# Why Dictionary "does not contain a definition for 'ElementAt'"?

Tags: c#, dictionary, dynamic

Why Dictionary "does not contain a definition for 'ElementAt'" during dynamic programming

```
        Dictionary<string, dynamic> D1 = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
        D1.Add("w1", 10);
        D1.Add("w2", false);
        Dictionary<string, dynamic> D2 = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
        D2.Add("v1", 10);
        D2.Add("v2", D1);
        textBox1.Text += D2.ElementAt(1).Value.ElementAt(1).Value;
```

we should get result on textbox1 "false"
But instead we will get run-time error: "does not contain a definition for 'ElementAt'"

if you will type:

```
        Dictionary<string, dynamic> var1 = D2.ElementAt(1).Value;
        textBox1.Text += var1.ElementAt(1).Value;
```

Then it will work correctly!

Comment: What makes you think you should get "false"? Bear in mind that dictionaries are not ordered. What is the *complete* run-time error?

Comment: D2.ElementAt(1).Value.ElementAt(0).Value   will be "10" but           D2.ElementAt(1).Value.ElementAt(1).Value   will be "false"

Comment: Dictionary does not contain `ElementAt` even without "dynamic programming" by the way.

Comment: if you will try D2["v2"].Value.ElementAt(1).Value then again you will get an error

Comment: For the same reason, as my answer explains. But you still seem to be over-confident that `D2.ElementAt(1)` returns the entry associated with key "v2" rather than the entry associated with key "v1". It may happen to work that way at the moment, but it's *not* guaranteed, and your code shouldn't make that assumption.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution, for me, I needed to add a reference to System.Linq and everything works, no modification to the code needed.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things wrong here:

- You're assuming that the second entry you added to `D2` is the one retrieved by `D2.ElementAt(1)`. Don't make that assumption: dictionaries are basically unordered.
- You're calling an extension method (`Enumerable.ElementAt`) on an expression of type `dynamic`

You can fix the second problem by just explicitly calling `Enumerable.ElementAt` as a static method:

```
textBox1.Text += Enumerable.ElementAt(D2.ElementAt(1).Value, 1).Value;
```

This will still leave the first part as a problem though. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, which means it's not clear what fix I should be suggesting to that part...

Comment: I Understood! Do you have any other Idea how to do it more compact way and more small amount of code?

Comment: @Iremadze: Well as I said, we can't really suggest anything when we don't know what you're trying to achieve.